# Api gateway integration with dynamodb giving 404

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use apiGateway as proxy to dynamodb but for some reason the integration returns 404.

I have created a patch method resource in apiGateway. and used below data in integration mappingTemplate for testing:

```
{
    "TableName": "Retool_Output",
    "Item": {
        "customerId": "1234",
        "fav_movies": "Shalini"
    }
}
```

but when i test this gateway, it does not update dynamodb and give 404 as shown below.

```
Tue Aug 06 17:03:56 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after 
transformations: {
    "TableName": "Retool_Output",
    "Item": {
        "customerId": "1234",
        "fav_movies": "Shalini"
    }
}
Tue Aug 06 17:03:56 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://dynamodb.ap- 
south-1.amazonaws.com//
Tue Aug 06 17:03:56 UTC 2019 : Received response. Status: 404, Integration 
latency: 13 ms
```

Can someone suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the url path is `/`? Haven't you configured an extra path like `/add-item`?

Comment: no i have not configured extra path. it's / only.

Comment: Have you deployed your stage? In the aws console there's a button "deploy api". It won't work if you didn't do that.

Comment: For some reason i am not able to create a stage. The deployment field is giving empty list.

Comment: Where are you trying to create it? On the console? (website)

Comment: yes it's on the console

Comment: Well when you open the deploy window from the method menu, there should be a option called [new stage]. Or try to go to the stages page from the left menu and create new stage, then deploy to it. Only when you deploy you will get a public link to send a request

Comment: Thanks @Mojimi. i have deployed the api gateway. but it is still getting 404 from db integration.

Comment: Then you're accessing it wrong, show us how you're testing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to the question. Basically we have to use POST method with action as PutItem for adding an item in dynamodb via apiGateway whereas I was using PUT method.

Comment: Yes we must "choose POST for the HTTP method since all DynamoDB Queries are POST":  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Comment: You got "404 Not Found" before because there is no non-POST endpoint to be found (for a DynamoDB Query).